# Flatten included files in msbuild project output

Tags: .net, msbuild, csproj

I have an MSBuild project using the new .Net SDK project format.

I'm trying to include files from outside the solution, which have their own folder structures and flatten that structure upon going to the build directory.

I.e.

```
Solution\
  Lib\
    lib1\
      file1.dll
      file2.dll
  lib2\
      file3.dll
      file3.dll
  Project\
     project.csproj
```

I want the entire structure under `\Lib` to be represented in my project in Visual Studio. I can do that with the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="$(SolutionDir)\Lib\**\*">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

The problem is, the output directory contains the same folder structure. I would like all the files flattened to simply exist in my `\bin` directory instead of `\bin\lib1\file1.dll`, `\bin\lib2\file3.dll`, etc.

Is there a way to handle this in the project file?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change it to

```
<None Include="$(SolutionDir)\Lib\**\*" TargetPath="%(Filename)%(Extension)" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
```

The updated target path will then no longer contain the subdirectories.

Comment: Does this work with the Content or Compile tags?

Comment: It should work for content, not sure about Compile at the moment